# Change only one label in an etaremune list without affecting the numbering

Tags: lists, enumerate, etaremune

I am using the package etarenume to make lists with decreasing labels instead of increasing. I am also using certain style for the labels, that I define locally for each list as follow:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
    \usepackage{etaremune}

    \begin{document}
    \renewcommand*{\labelenumi}{[M\theenumi]}
      \begin{etaremune}
           \item first item
           \item second item (with asterisk)
           \item third item
      \end{etaremune}
    \end{document}
```

I would like to change one label in a list without affecting the numbering. In particular I would like to add an asterisk to one label. I tried the following

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
    \usepackage{etaremune}

    \begin{document}
    \renewcommand*{\labelenumi}{[M\theenumi]}
      \begin{etaremune}
           \item first item
           \item[*\labelenumi] second item (with asterisk)
           \item third item
      \end{etaremune}
    \end{document}
```

which gives the following

[image]

As you can see, now the numbering is not correct, because the item with the customized label did not increase the counter (I guess). How can one fix this problem?

Comment: `\renewcommand*{\labelenumi}{*[M\theenumi]}` before the item and then back again?